# How To Handle a User Clicking the X Button in Facebook Login DIalog In Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, webview, sdk

In Facebook SDK (Android), I check to see if a session exists and if not, I use this code to open it:

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            Bundle bundle = session.getAuthorizationBundle();

            Log.d(TAG, "BUNDLE "+bundle);

            if (session.isOpened() && session != null && isPosted) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();

                path = (String)intent.getExtras().get("path");
                Log.d(TAG, "PATH" + path.toString());

                // if credentials, just get user name and password
                try{
                    String creds = (String)intent.getExtras().get("onlyCredentials");
                    credentials = Boolean.parseBoolean(creds);
                } catch(NullPointerException e){
                    e.getMessage();

                    credentials = false;
                }

                if(credentials){
                    getCredentials(session);
                } else {
                    doPosts(session, path);
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

This will pop open a login window (dialog). Here is how it looks:

[image: Facebook Login Dialog]

**Things To Know about this application**

- This app will be installed ONLY on tablets owned by businesses doing business with us. That means users will not have it on their smartphones.
- This app requires clearing of sessions once a user has logged in using their Facebook account - and that is properly working.
- The problem now is that I am trying to handle a situation where they try to login and then decide before entering their email and password to click the **X** button on the top left of the dialog window.
- I am using Facebook SDK 3.6
- We do not have the Facebook App installed intentionally, because we want to have multiple users using the app one after the other; Having the Facebook app will cause issues with sessions and stuff like that.

And this is the window that shows up when you click the **X** button:

[image: Window that shows when you click X button]

If there is any question you want me to answer, please ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hack - well, I wouldn't really call it a hack but something to try. Figured out that you could hide the **X** button while displaying the login web dialog.

If you look inside **WebDialog.java** inside Facebook Module under widget, you will find the button and all you need to do is comment out the code that adds it to the view. Here is the code inside **onCreate()** method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            sendCancelToListener();
        }
    });

    spinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    spinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    spinner.setMessage(getContext().getString(R.string.com_facebook_loading));
    spinner.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            sendCancelToListener();
            WebDialog.this.dismiss();
        }
    });

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    contentFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());

    // First calculate how big the frame layout should be
    calculateSize();
    getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    // resize the dialog if the soft keyboard comes up
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

    /* Create the 'x' image, but don't add to the contentFrameLayout layout yet
     * at this point, we only need to know its drawable width and height
     * to place the webview
     */
    createCrossImage();

    /* Now we know 'x' drawable width and height,
     * layout the webview and add it the contentFrameLayout layout
     */
    int crossWidth = crossImageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();

    setUpWebView(crossWidth / 2 + 1);

    /* Finally add the 'x' image to the contentFrameLayout layout and
    * add contentFrameLayout to the Dialog view
    */
   //        contentFrameLayout.addView(crossImageView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
   //                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    setContentView(contentFrameLayout);
}
```

Here is how it looks without it:

[image: Hiding the Facebook Login cancel button]

You can then alternatively add your own cancel button for users to cancel out gracefully!

**EDIT -  Without Breaking Facebook's Terms of Service:**

This piece of code will actually handle two things when a user clicks the X button or denies access to your app:

- First, it will handle the exception for clicking **X** and also
- Secondly, it will gracefully handle the exception for not giving permissions

  ```
  Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

          if (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
              Log.d("Facebook", "User canceled!!");
              Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

              startActivity(intent);
          }
         if (session.isOpened() && session != null && isPosted) {
              Intent intent = getIntent();

              path = (String) intent.getExtras().get("path");
              Log.d(TAG, "PATH" + path.toString());

              // if credentials, just get user name and password
              try {
                  String creds = (String) intent.getExtras().get("onlyCredentials");
                  credentials = Boolean.parseBoolean(creds);
              } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                  e.getMessage();

                  credentials = false;
              }

              if (credentials) {
                  getCredentials(session);
              } else {
                  doPosts(session, path);
              }
         }
      }
  });
  ```

That is how you handle this problem and I hope someone else finds it helpful. Good luck and thanks to @RED_ for responding to this question.

**NOTE** 
You don't have to edit the Facebook Module anymore since you are letting users actually click the cancel button. Again, hiding the button might be against Facebook's Developer Terms of Use - you don't want to get sued.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is presuming the user will not have Facebook the Facebook app.

As we talked about in chat, it is very likely they will. Your app might be for business use but they will have Facebook for personal use.

Your app requires Facebook, so surely they will have to install it or login via the browser. All you have to do is check the session again and give them an alertdialog to tell them it is necessary.

The X button is there for a reason. Also the web browser login is a backup to not having the Facebook app. If anything you want them to have it.

**Edit:** What happens if you press the back button while on the black screen? The thing is you have to remember that if this client of your knows only certain people will use the app, they will understand the login and press back again to login again. You have to run it by your client and it's user to see the reaction.

Comment: The app is on our own hardware - that means there will be no other apps installed. No one will install the Facebook App on it. We own it.

Comment: Made an edit to my post. If it is your hardware my not pre-install facebook too. As you know it is needed, the benefit of the facebook app is that it will always ask for permissions in your app.

Comment: If I press the back button, it goes to the screen the user was on before going to the Login page. That is the screen with all the images to select one from.

Comment: I should also mention the fact that introducing the Facebook app itself gives the control to the user here - which we don't want. All we want is to let them login, give permissions and our code will do the rest of the job: posting to Facebook wall/pages. We then redirect them back to some other stuff.

Comment: You can check for permission with a facebook request, and deny them access if they do not have the facebook permissions. Even you do it via the browser it will still give them control, they will be able to change things in their settings page so nobody can see it or whatever else.

Comment: Using this Dialog, all they get to do is allow permissions after login and the window goes away and I redirect them. They get no control whatsoever - they cannot change anything because they can only login, give permissions and done.

Comment: The Facebook app will work the same way. This is something you have to discuss with your client, not on SO. The facebook app will only accept permissions and nothing else. If that's how you set it up then it will still do it exactly, how you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48394/discussion-between-eenvincible-and-red)